# Is it professional to use jquery mobile for an iPhone app

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile

I have a question, I was wondering if it is professional to use jQuery mobile for a iPhone app? I mean, i just needed to create photo galleries and i used jQuery mobile, and then created a webview for it.

Is it OK to create an iPhone app this way? Or is it not professional? Thanks!

Comment: Why would it not be professional? It's a popular, free and wide used library. You could also write everything yourself, but why would you do that?

Comment: I don't know.. it's just that it seems to be easy enough :)
Well thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone will have an opinion about whether it is professional or not... it all depends on how you deliver your final product.

If your app looks polished, performs well and adheres to the HIG guidelines, then yes, it could be acceptable.

If you however throw something together which looks bad, performs poorly and doesn't function, then don't bother. You'd likely not make it past the approval process.

Take a look at: http://www.jqmgallery.com/. Lots of people have used jQuery Mobile to produce really slick looking apps.

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Ask the basic questions -

1. Can I maintain it easily
2. Can someone else maintain it easily
3. Does it work with my SCM
4. Does it meet the requirements - fast enough, no crashing, etc.

It's professional, as long as you use best practices, and write decent scripts.